# Open different php files on one div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to ask about how to open different PHP files in one div.

I have a `dashboard.php` with `#principal` div. The dashboard file is divided in 2 parts - one is the menu (with include ("menu.php");)also the menu.php has a CSS MENU ... and (I want to link to the different php files and the Div who is the principal where I want to load the different files....

Is that possible?

Code for: dashboard.php:

```
 <body id="main">
   <header id="topbar">
     <img src="./img/logo_toco_small.png">
   </header>
   <nav id="menu">
     <?PHP include ("menu.php"); ?>
   </nav>
   <hr class="dashboard">
   <div id="principal" class="target"></div>
   <footer class="footer">
     <?PHP include ("footer.php"); ?>
   </footer>
 </body>
```

This is the menu.php

```
<ul class="flatflipbuttons">
  <li><a href="" class="ttip" title ="Inicio" data-tooltip="Inicio" href="./dashboard.php"><span class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="" class="ttip" title ="Clientes" data-tooltip="Cientes" ><span class="fa fa-users fa-fw"></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="" class="ttip" title ="Proveedores" data-tooltip="Proveedores"><span class="fa fa-truck fa-fw"></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="" class="ttip" title ="Usuarios" data-tooltip="Usuarios"><span class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="" class="ttip" title ="Partes" data-tooltip="Partes"><span class="fa fa-puzzle-piece fa-fw"></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="" class="ttip" title ="Productos" data-tooltip="Productos"><span class="fa fa-dropbox fa-fw"></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="" class="ttip" title ="Proyectos" data-tooltip="Proyectos"><span class="fa fa-th-list fa-fw"></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="" class="ttip" title ="Compras" data-tooltip="Compras"><span class="fa fa-dollar fa-fw"></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="" class="ttip" title ="Movimientos" data-tooltip="Movimientos"><span class="fa fa-undo fa-fw"></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="" class="ttip" title ="Reportes" data-tooltip="Reportes"><span class="fa fa-line-chart fa-fw"></span></a></li>
  <li><a title ="Cotizacion"  target="principal" class="ttip" data-tooltip="Cotizaciones"><span class="fa fa-calculator fa-fw"></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="./exit.php" class="ttip" data-tooltip="Salir" title ="Salir" ><span class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

menu and dashboard php files are in the same dir. thanks in advance.

Comment: My tip, don't have empy `href` atrributes, make them meaningful so Search Engines can disvorer your content easier, you can then access the `href` attribute via javascript/jquery to loag up your div.

Comment: for the comment for HREF attributtes is a offline system ... but anyways thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love this way:

```
$(function() {

  if (Modernizr.history) {

    // history is supported; do magical things

    // hijack the nav click event
    $(".flatflipbuttons").on( "click", "a", function(event) {

      event.preventDefault();
      _href = $(this).attr("href");

      // change the url without a page refresh and add a history entry.
      history.pushState(null, null, _href);

      // load the content
      loadContent(_href); // fear not! we're going to build this function in the next code block

    });

  } else {

    // history is not supported; nothing fancy here

  }

});
// set up some variables
var $mainContent = $("#principal"),
    $pageWrap    = $("#main"),
    baseHeight   = 0;

// calculate wrapper heights to prevent jumping when loading new content
$pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

function loadContent(href) {

  $mainContent
    .find("#main-content")
    .fadeOut(200, function() { // fade out the content of the current page
      $mainContent
        .hide()
        .load(href + " #main-content", function() { // load the contents of whatever href is
          $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
            $pageWrap.animate({
              height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + &quot;px&quot;
            });
         });

    });

  });

}
```

Some changes to **HTML**

```
<body id="main">

   <header id="topbar"><img src="./img/logo_toco_small.png"></header>
   <nav id="menu"><?PHP include ("menu.php"); ?></nav>
   <hr class="dashboard">   

   <div id="principal" class="target">
      <div id="main-content">

          //  Main content goes here...

      </div>
    </div>

   <footer class="footer"> <?PHP include ("footer.php"); ?></footer>

</body>


//  menu.php
<ul class="flatflipbuttons">
    <li><a href="dashboard.php" class="ttip" title ="Inicio" data-tooltip="Inicio"><span class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="users.php"  class="ttip" title ="Clientes" data-tooltip="Cientes" ><span class="fa fa-users fa-fw"></span></a></li>
    ...
    <li><a href="exit.php" class="ttip" data-tooltip="Salir" title ="Salir" ><span class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

> This answer is taken from [**CSS-Tricks**](http://css-tricks.com/rethinking-dynamic-page-replacing-content/)

Comment: I like this answer, but it will not immediately apply to the question as posed. For expample, different ids, empty href attributes, etc. You should at least indicate what need to be changed to the OP to implement this.

Comment: its necesary to menu to be included and not be separated,can't work with separated structure?

Comment: what do you mean by separated structure? Your put navigation links on the page, put content box for pages and apply js function on the links, so by clicking a link jquery loads a page and url change happen. It's like not ajax app, but it is...

Comment: it's ok i dont put atention for it. i need to read twice to understand, i can put this in a JS file? ..

Comment: no problem, yes you can. Just put attention to include Modernizr.js or get rid of the if statement

Comment: one more question my PHP files who are the ones, that be loaded in the DIV . are in "modulos" folder... i put a /modulos/clientes.php in href?? sry... if i messed up

Comment: Yes. Or you can prepend /modulos/ in load function

Comment: i changed the file but isn't working... opens the "page" but not in the desired div

Comment: Updated the answer with `event.preventDefault()`, also inside your pages must to be `div#main-content`. Can you link to your code?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7LubRcmV -for menu.php ... http://pastebin.com/RpiSSP7v ... for abrirmodulo.hs ..

Comment: LoL ... i think the problem is my side... i try the sudojesse - dynamic-page and works perfectly ... im change my page to identically structure and dont work ...

Comment: LoL im searching the modernizr.js cdn ... and actually.. works ... but if i click again (puts /modulos/modulos/listado_cotizacion.php)

Comment: Ok, try to put full path in your href

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using jquery

```
$( window ).load(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    var href_id = $(this).attr('id');
    if ( href_id != null ) {
      $(".target").html( "Loading.... Please Wait." );
      $(".target").load( href_id + ".php");
    }
  )};
});
```

So just add each link with an id name that match your wanna be included php file name.

Comment: ho ... i forgot... the php who i want to open are in "modulos" folder, i edit it(your code-im not want to be 'rude').. but is not open ... can you help me... thaks ...

Comment: Do you mean to load the php file under /modulos/?  then you can try use $(".target").load( "/modulos/" + href_id + ".php" );